# Magento 2.2.3: Enable agreements always disabled

Tags: magento2, bug, terms-and-conditions

Dashboard >> Stores >> Configurations >> Sales >> Checkout Options >> Enable Terms and Condition always set NO after saved value as YES many times.

```
Magento Version: 2.2.3
Control Panel: Plesk Onyx
Server: Nginx
```

[image]

Comment: Can you check if any observer set this to No everytime. As I had faced the similar type of issue but not for this section. I found that one magento extension set the value to Yes every time when page loaded through observer.

Comment: Yes, it could be possible, but how can i check this, This is live site and in database values is changing zero and one (enable/disable) but it remains to no and unable to see on front-end.

Comment: @SukumarGorai, I have enabled it in backend but orders are not placed. can you please check. Same issue for all the payment methods not only for paypal